# Prevent Linux from writing to HDD

Tags: windows, hard-disk, read, write

I have 3 HDD's, I want to install Linux Mint on HDD 3 which is currently empty and I don't want Linux to be able to write any data on the other 2 which is where all my Windows files are, is there a way to tell Linux these are read only or block them entirely?

Comment: If you install Linux to a partition it will only write to that partition. i.e It will not write to Windows.

Comment: The kernel will have permission to write in all your disks if you mount it. So it depends only on you...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount the volumes under the `/etc/fstab` files with instead of choosing `defaults` as the 4th option, select the `ro` option with others as necessary. Details on the options can be read at `man mount 8`. The option for ntfs file system may be different on your version of linux so you may have to research it more but the just of it should be the same setting the mount options as read only.

Examples of setting up the fstab could be found at these answers
https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab

#### Example of fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       ext4     defaults        1 1
/dev/sdb2               /windows                ntfs-3g     ro,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async        0 0
```